# Dropdown gets stuck beneath my svg container

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Im trying to have a Menu when you click it, it dropsdown which works, but it gets stuck under my SVG so i can't see it I can see like half of the first item in the dropdown but nothing more I dont know how to fix it any help ?

I have tried with index but I might have done it wrong since it didnt work.

```
 <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="header-content">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <img src="Icons/menu.png" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"></button>
          <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img src="Imgs/logo.jpeg" class="logo" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <main>
"My SVG"
</main>
  </body>
```

And my CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #fff5ee;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 1100px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff5ee;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  order: 1;
  float: left;
  
}

.dropbtn {
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff5ee;
}

.dropdown-content a:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```